# IOS wkwebview does not work with mailto link or tel link

Tags: codenameone

We rencently update the webbrowser component, from **UIwebview** to **WKwebview** because *Apple* rejects the compilation.

Since we change the component mailto and tel link does not work.

Any solution?.

Best Regards Kandy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I opted to disable the WKwebview for the pages who contains those link, because overriding the navigate method dont work, the event dont fired with the "tel" link and the "emailto" link throw an error although I response false on the fireBrowserNavigationCallbacks method.

Now before create the BrowserComponent with UIwebView I put to false the property:

```
Display.getInstance().setProperty("BrowserComponent.useWKWebView", "false");
```

And when I want to use the new WKwebview I put to true:

```
Display.getInstance().setProperty("BrowserComponent.useWKWebView", "true");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke these features in the `Display` class in Codename One. You can expose them through the web by overriding the browser navigate functionality and detecting these URLs.